# Javascript Chaining return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem for getting this OOP works. basically, this `$("notfound")` is not on document. it put an error. but if change it to `$("parent")` it works because it is on document.

check this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/k6j70f1h/8/

in console.log the child is undefined.

how to get this things works?

what's wrong with my code?

```js
"use strict"

var $, i;

(function() {

    $ = function(el, context) {
      context = context || document;
        return new obj$(el, context);
    };

    var obj$ = function(el, context) {
       var cl   = context.getElementsByClassName(el),
           loop = cl.length;

       this.length = loop;

       for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
           this[i] = cl[i];
       }

   };

   obj$.prototype = {

       find : function(el) {

           if (this.length == 1) {

               return $( el, this[0] );
           }

       },
       css : function(obj, data) {

           if (this.length == 1) {
               this[0].style[obj] = data;
               return this;
           }

        }
    };


})();

var parent = $("notfound"), // this one cause error
    child  = parent.find("child"); // throw an error child is undefined

child.css("color", "orange");
parent.css("color", "purple");
```

```html
<div class="parent">parent
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your current expression,you are trying to find a reference of a child tag. In order to find the element with class "child" , you need to append . (period) in the selector.  parent.find(".child")

Comment: @DinoMyte: No, the OP's `$` function (which is not jQuery) expects just the class name, not a selector. It uses `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Ching Ching: your answer will work if you change 

<div class="parent">

to 

<div class="notfound">

Comment: You must *always* return another instance (or yourself). Not just in some cases.

Comment: @ Crawdingle, yup, i know that. but somehow those element not exist on page. especially when u change the page.

Comment: This is [the third same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548291/javascript-chaining-function-oop-not-working)  today : (.

Comment: @ChingChing: **Do not delete and repost questions**. If you don't get a useful answer, edit your question to improve details, etc.

Comment: @Teemu, sorry i have been struggle for 12 hours. still can't figure out, how to make this things works. i'm so sorry. i learn code with my self, no guidance. sorrry

Comment: @ChingChing Don't worry, nothing personal, I just happened to remember the code. But deleting a lot of questions leads you to question ban. Always edit your question rather than delete it. Notice, that editing a question brings it on top on [Active tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=active&pageSize=15), and it will get more visibility for a moment.

Comment: @Teemu, whoa, i just know that trick. i'm waiting for 3 hours. nobody respond. what i get was downvotes overtime. i try to chat. yet nobody answer. thanks Teemu for your trick!

Comment: @ChingChing Just remember not to abuse the feature. Cosmetic improvements are shooted down quickly, and you'll get more down votes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you've said is causing the error is not causing the error.

The line causing the error is:

```
child.css("color", "orange");
```

It's causing the error because this line:

```
var parent = $("notfound"),
```

...returns a `parent` object with `length == 0`, and so this line:

```
child  = parent.find("child"); // throw an error child is undefined
```

...calls `find` on an object where `this.length` is not `1`, so the code in `find` doesn't go into the body of your `if` statement and you don't return anything. That means calling `parent.find(...)` results in `undefined`, which you've assigned to `child`. Thus, `child.css(...)` is an attempt to call `css` on `undefined`.

If you want to make something jQuery-like, you'll want to add

```
return $();
```

...find `parent.find` if `this.length` is 0 (at a minimum):

```
find : function(el) {
    if (this.length == 1) {
        return $( el, this[0] );
    }
    return $();
}
```

Similarly, if you want to emulate jQuery, you'll **always** want to `return this` from your `css` function, not just if you have an element.

Here's an update with the minimum necessary changes:

```js
"use strict"

var $, i;

(function() {

    $ = function(el, context) {
      context = context || document;
        return new obj$(el, context);
    };

    var obj$ = function(el, context) {
       var cl   = context.getElementsByClassName(el),
           loop = cl.length;

       this.length = loop;

       for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
           this[i] = cl[i];
       }

   };

   obj$.prototype = {

       find : function(el) {

           if (this.length == 1) {

               return $( el, this[0] );
           }

           return $();                       // Added
       },
       css : function(obj, data) {

           if (this.length == 1) {
               this[0].style[obj] = data;
           }
           return this;                      // Moved

        }
    };


})();

var parent = $("notfound"), // this one cause error
    child  = parent.find("child"); // throw an error child is undefined

child.css("color", "orange");
parent.css("color", "purple");
```

```html
<div class="parent">parent
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks TJ for answering. i try ur method. now it puts an error "context is undefined". what's this? i don't understand. please help. thanks. can you make a fiddle that  working?

Comment: @ChingChing: Ah, I should have used `$()`, not `new obj$()`. Fixed.

Comment: @TJ, wow that's working! awesome!, anyway would you like to see this fiddle a moment? i don't know what;s wrong. i try add another method. but it's not working. no error on console.log. it;s weird. https://jsfiddle.net/k6j70f1h/10/